# When should I pass something to saveHTML() function?

Tags: php

All I want to know what's the difference between these:

```
$post_content_html = $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);
```

And

```
$post_content_html = $dom->saveHTML();
```

My tests say there isn't any different. But when exactly should I pass `$dom->documentElement` to `saveHTML()` function?

---

My full code which removes all attributes except specific ones:

```
// to make tags stable, wrap them into <html> tag
$post_content_html = "<html>".$post_content_html."</html>"

$dom = new DOMDocument;              
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($post_content_html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//@*');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {             
    if($node->nodeName != "src" && $node->nodeName != "href" && $node->nodeName != "alt") {
        $node->parentNode->removeAttribute($node->nodeName);
    }
}
// maybe I have to pass $dom->documentElement to the saveHTML() function
$post_content_html = $dom->saveHTML();

// string <html> tag which been wrapped
$post_content_html = preg_replace('/^<html>/', '', $post_content_html);
$post_content_html = preg_replace('/<\/html>$/', '', $post_content_html);
```

Comment: Never, because as you noted, that does nothing. Instead, try passing a different `DOMNode` to it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I've added my full code, still are you believe I shouldn't pass `$dom->documentElement` to it?

Comment: Passing `documentElement` literally does nothing.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I see, thank you .. also as a consult, I add `<html>` tag surround the input because I want to keep tags in the right place. I mean, see [this](https://3v4l.org/qt1Kr), if I don't wrap it into `<html>` tag, the position of `<p>` tag will be changed. So what I'm doing is right?

Answer (score 3):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php):

The first argument is:

> Optional parameter to output a subset of the document.

So you pass it an argument if you don't want to save the whole document.

There is no point is passing it the `documentElement` since that is the whole document.

Comment: Thank you .. upvote. Just one thing, I've added my full code, still are you believe I shouldn't pass `$dom->documentElement` to it?